# grep/sed copy two identic file names in a directory

Tags: linux, macos, file, console

I am going to execute the sed command on Mac OSX El Capitan:

```
grep -rl 'efefef' . | xargs sed -i ' ' "s/efefef/cccccc/g"
```

If I do the command the really strange thing is, if the grep command find this expression, the command is copying the file into the same directory with the SAME filename. How is it possible?!?

```
-rw-r--r--  1 craphunter  staff  12605 16 Okt 14:40 backend_pay.de.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 craphunter  staff  12694 15 Okt 16:41 backend_pay.de.yml
```

Now I do have two files with the same FILENAME in the SAME directory?!?!?

Any idea? How is it even possible?!

Thanks!

craphunter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a space to the backup file's name:

```
sed -i ' '
```

Use something more distinctive, like `~`.

Comment: Oh crap! THANKS! Of course! Is it possible to do it without a backup?

Comment: @craphunter: Some versions of `sed` allow for `-i` without an argument. The question is why? If you do it wrong, the backup is handy!